# IExplorer float not working properly on hover (all versions)

Tags: internet-explorer, hover

I have a problem with IE: when I go with the cursor on images (that have a :hover opacity change, but I don't know if it's relevant), it happen to mess up all the float.
You can see it in [this page](http://www.wigiks.it/P_O_v3/_it_/gallery-matrimoni.php).

Every version of Explorer is affected.

Also: what is about with the link on the main logo? Why two overlapped images are so problematic with IE? (no :hover here)

Thanks everyone and be patient: it's my first question over on SO.